# simple modal login plugin

Tags: wordpress, authentication, simplemodal

I already have a modal window for login using simple modal login,I need to have another modal window in the same page when a link is clicked to create account,which will also be a modal window.How can I have multiple modal windows using simple modal Login plugin ?What files do I need to change in order to achieve that? please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many modals on the page as you like but only ever one at any one time.

```
$("#element-one").modal({options});
$("#element-two").modal({options});
```

Put the above code in the same place as the other JS on the page and put your html link in wherever you want it to appear on your site.

```
<a href="#" id="element-two">Link to activate 2nd Simple Modal</a>
```

The plugin uses the jQuery simple modal plugin so you can look through the documentation there for more help:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/